# How big is the ledger?

Tags: ledger, nodes, validators

The public ledger adds a new entry every 3-5 seconds. So I am worried it might grow too big for normal users to run a node. How big is the current ledger and how much is it expected to grow each year?

Comment: By "how big" you mean how much data storage it takes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**updated 2019-10-15**

Public network:

- Current total ledgers count: **26315419**
- Core database size (fully synced): **657 GB**
- Horizon database size (fully synced): **1.2 TB**
- History archives: **175 GB**

Comment: The only thing missing is how big is history archive. I don't have a full history to check that.

Comment: What exactly are the values meaning for ledger count? Is it each time the ledger gets settled (every 3-5 seconds)? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. New ledger is generated each SCP round. https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/ledger.html

Answer (score 15):

Won't be able to tell exact number, but this is not an issue.

Stellar has different levels of participation. Only archiver and full validator nodes publish archive and maintain full history.

[image]

Also this archive doesn't need to be stored on the server, it can be published to S3 bucket or any other cloud storage.

Nodes keep current state of the network and can be configured how many ledgers to maintain using stellar-core configuration option `CATCHUP_RECENT`.