# What is the storage size and growth rate for the Live network?

Tags: stellar-core, network, history

I would like to sync with the live net, but so far couldn't search for any discussion on the costs and growth rate (archive & postgres).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some information on current storage size [here](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/153/366). As for the growth rate, nobody can predict how much transactions per second we can expect even in the next month. Number of accounts metric demonstrate [steady growth](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/).